# Using X.PagedList on a modal pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagedlist

I've got a modal pop up on a page:

```
...
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="companySearchModal" aria-hidden="true" id="companySearchModal"> 
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> 
         <div class="modal-content"> 
           <div id="companySearchModalContent"></div> 
         </div><!-- /.modal-content --> 
     </div><!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
   </div><!-- /.modal -->
...
```

That I pop up:

```
...
    $('#companySearchModalContent').html(data); 
    $('#companySearchModal').modal(options); 
    $('#companySearchModal').modal('show');
...
```

On that modal dialog I display a list of companies with this **PagedListPager** on the bottom setup like this:

```
<div>
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

    <div id="companySearchPager">
        @Html.PagedListPager(
                                Model,
                                page => Url.Action("CompanySearch",
                                                   "Admin",
                                                     new
                                                          {
                                                              sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
                                                              currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter,
                                                              page = page
                                                     }),
                                PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
                                    new AjaxOptions
                                        {
                                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                                            UpdateTargetId = "companySearchModalContent"
                                        }
                                    )
                                )
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on a given page element rendered by the **PagedListPager** control it does call the the Action "**CompanySearch**" from the Controller "**Admin**" as specified in the **Url.Action** but it renders the **PartialView** that is returned all by itself on the whole page instead of injecting the partial view into the **"#companySearchModalContent"** Div I've set as the **UpdateTargetId** in the **AjaxOptions** of the **PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing** call.

I figured the PagedListPager would do this.  I added some jQuery code to call the appropriate ajax injection "**$('#companySearchModalContent').html(data);**" but I don't have a way to get the page number, search and sort parameters to come along with that the user clicked on from the pager control and don't know how to set the *url* and *data* appropriately in the .ajax code block.

```
$('#companySearchPager').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({           
        type: 'GET',
        // How to get the page value the user clicked on?
        // data: {"page": #},
        // How to get the url? This would work if I could get the page #.
        // url: '@Url.Action("CompanySearch", "Admin")',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $('#companySearchModalContent').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            showAlert("Employer content load failed.", "warning", 5000);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I would expect the PageListPager to make that "$('#companySearchModalContent').html(data);" call for me given that I've set the UpdateTargetId in the AjaxOptions of the PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing call.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the newel post!

Added

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

at the top of the page.